# OpenEdx: load python script from file

Tags: python, openedx

I was able to write a python script to check an edx problem between  tags.
However I would like to include a python function from a file, in order to reuse the code in several problems.
I tried the following code:

```
<problem>
  <script type="loncapa/python" src="/static/textinput.py" />

  <customresponse cfn="check_function">
    <script type="loncapa/python">
<![CDATA[
import json

def check_function(e, ans):

# ... my code ...

    </script>

    <jsinput
      gradefn="getGrade"
      get_statefn="getState"
      set_statefn="setState"
             initial_state='{"selectedChoice": "[]"}'
      width="600"
      html_file="/static/Ex1_3 v2.html"
      title="Problem"
      sop="false"/>
  </customresponse>
</problem>
```

I get the following error when saving the problem:

> Problem block-v1:Casal+Basic1+1701+type@problem+block@55479f8087e64d2395b730037cbe83c3 has an error:
>   cannot create LoncapaProblem block-v1:Casal+Basic1+1701+type@problem+block@55479f8087e64d2395b730037cbe83c3: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/capa_base.py",  line 234, in **init**
>         self.lcp = self.new_lcp(self.get_state_for_lcp())
>         File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/capa_base.py", line 328, in new_lcp
>         capa_module=self,  # njp   File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/capa/capa/capa_problem.py", line 192, in **init**
>        self.context = self._extract_context(self.tree)
>        Files "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/capa/capa/capa_problem.py", line 728, in _extract_context
>        code = unescape(script.text, XMLESC)
>        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxutils.py", line 46, in unescape
>        data = data.replace("<", "<")

Is it possible to do this? If so, is it correct to use the tag:? Of course the file textinput.py is uploaded and works well in python.

> `<script type="loncapa/python" src="/static/textinput.py" />`

Comment: Add your code corespondents to the `Traceback`.

Comment: Btw, I don't have access to the platform, so I should resolve it with the course resources or coding HTML or Python inside the problem component

Comment: Are you sure that your code is properly formatted? It seems that it is the XML parsing step that is failing.